# Joining records from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table test that contains data as shown below:

```
id  id1 id2 id3     date1
1   1   2   2500    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000
2   1   2   4700    2005-01-01 00:00:00.000
3   1   2   4700    2009-08-01 00:00:00.000
4   1   3   2500    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000
5   1   3   4700    2003-02-01 00:00:00.000
6   1   8   4000    2007-04-01 00:00:00.000
7   1   8   4000    2013-09-01 00:00:00.000
8   1   8   4060    2007-04-01 00:00:00.000
9   1   8   8500    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000
```

What I need to do is order this data in the following format:

```
id1 id2 id3     date1                   date2
1   2   2500    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   2   4700    2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 2009-07-31 00:00:00.000
1   2   4700    2009-08-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   3   2500    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   3   4700    2003-02-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   8   4000    2007-04-01 00:00:00.000 2013-08-31 00:00:00.000
1   8   4000    2013-09-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   8   4060    2007-04-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   8   8500    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
```

Using the following logic:

- If there is only one record for the same id1, id2 and id3 we use the original date for date1 and we use the maximum date available in sql server (9999-12-31) for date2.
- If there is more than one record for the same id1, id2 and id3 we still keep the original date for date1 and we use for date2 the original date field minus 1 day from the next record . The last record will use also the maximum date available in sql server (9999-12-31) for date2.

I manage to build the following query but it is not perfect as it brings some invalid records:

```
select * from 
(select 
t1.id1,t1.id2,t1.id3,t1.date1,
case
when t1.date1=t2.date1 then CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/9999 23:59:59.997')
else DATEADD(day, -1, t2.date1)
end as date2
from test t1
inner join test t2
on t1.id1=t2.id1 and t1.id2=t2.id2 and t1.id3=t2.id3
) sub
where date2>=date1 
order by id1,id2,id3,date1 asc
```

The result of the query is:

```
id1 id2 id3     date1                   date2
1   2   2500    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   2   4700    2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997 *
1   2   4700    2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 2009-07-31 00:00:00.000
1   2   4700    2009-08-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   3   2500    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   3   4700    2003-02-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   8   4000    2007-04-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997 *
1   8   4000    2007-04-01 00:00:00.000 2013-08-31 00:00:00.000
1   8   4000    2013-09-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   8   4060    2007-04-01 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
1   8   8500    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
```

As you can see, the records marked with * are not necessary but I don't know how to get rid off that rows.

Comment: Why are you subtracting one day?  If you're dealing with timestamps, you're going to miss out on essentially 24 hours worth of data.  It would be better to keep `date2` as the other value, to enable [simple end-date querying](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - There is no such thing as an end-date, only the start of the next state.  I'd also use `null` in the case where there isn't a known end-date, rather than a high-val (which may change in a future version!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
select id1,id2,id3, date1, 
isnull(lead(date1) over(partition by id1,id2,id3 order by date1)-1, '99991231') as date2
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT t1.id1, t1.id2, t1.id3, t1.date1 as date1,
    ISNULL(t2.date1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/9999 23:59:59.997')) as date2
FROM test t1
    LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id1 AND t1.id2 = t2.id2 AND t1.id3 = t2.id3
        AND t1.id < t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id1, t1.id2, t1.id3, date1, date2
```

Comment: It also brings invalid records